# Problem converting my computer to ubuntu due to inability to navigate bios

Tags: boot

I wish to replace windows/vista operating system on an old Lenovo/IBM computer with ubuntu.  I downloaded ubuntu to a CD.  However, when I enter the bios program to change the boot priorty, I get a message saying that the boot priority can only be changed in supervisor mode.  I don't know how to get to "supervisor mode".

Comment: Generally that involves entering a bios password, but that's a hardware specific issue unrelated to Ubuntu and so is off topic.

Comment: off topic here.  There is some information of Supervisor mode for Lenovo here: [How to change/remove and set a supervisor password](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=YAST-3JZS7U)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, F2 or F11 or F12 will give you change boot sequence without getting into the BIOS. Please check if one of them works.